# javascript variable's weird behaviour

Tags: javascript

Case 1 - If I console.log(variable) before the variable declaration I get undefined. eg;

```
  // code 
  console.log(a);
  var a ;

  // output
  undefined
```

Case 2 - If I console.log(variable) without variable declaration I get  Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined.

```
// code
console.log(a);

// output
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

But incase of functions we can call a function before or after function definition it never give any issue. eg;

```
  console.log(example());

  function example(){
    return 'test done';
  }
  console.log(example());

 // output without any issue
```

Now My question is, what is the difference between **undefined** and **not defined**.

Comment: Please do research more and google around it to get the answer automatically :)

Comment: `var` and `function` declarations are hoisted. Welcome to JS.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var  search for "hoisting"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/497418 would be good to read as well. This particular behavior is hard to search for when you don't understand what's going on. Don't feel too bad about the downvotes.

Comment: This is because of the way the JS engine compiles functions VS variable. Undefined is a type in Javascript that is a variable has not been initialized to a value yet. Functions are hoisted so that you can call them from anywhere in your code (scope permitting).

Answer (score 5):

Undefined means - variable exists, but have no any stored value in it.
Not defined means - variable not declared (not exist).